How many ways can we distribute 10 difference looking pencils to 7 students, every student should at least receive one pencil?
To distribute 10 different cards to 7 students, we can calculate the number of combinations.
Since the cards are distinct, the order in which they are distributed does not matter. We are simply interested in the different ways to choose which cards go to each student.
Using combinations, the number of ways to distribute the 10 different cards among the 7 students can be calculated as 10 choose 7.
Calculating this expression:
(10!) / (7! * (10-7)!) = (10 * 9 * 8) / (3 * 2 * 1) = 120
Therefore, there are 120 different combinations to distribute 10 different cards to 7 students.

Where is the question here?

This is far too small .  Even if you pick $4$ to give to the first student,  there are $6!$ ways to distribute the other $6$.

Note: you sometimes say "pencils" and sometimes  "cards". You should pick one.

By the way, you have misinterpreted the question. It says every student should receive at least one penci, it would seem that the question wants you to distribute all the pencils

Actually you are asked: "how many surjections $[10]\to[7]$ are there?"

The possibilities are: four pencils to one student, one to each of the others; three to one student, two to another, one to each of the others; two to each of three students, one to each of the others. Count how many ways to achieve each of these possibilities; then, add.

The computation of $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{7}~$ is wrong, because it represents assuming that only $~7~$ pencils will be distributed, and computing how many ways that there are to select these $~7~$ pencils.  So, this computation really has nothing to do with the problem.
My approach to solving this will be to identify each individual way that $~10~$ pencils can be integer partitioned into $~7~$ non-zero numbers, compute the number of ways that each mutually exclusive partition can occur, and then add the computations together.

Since you are (in effect) starting with a tableau that looks like
1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1

you really are only partitioning the number $~3,~$ which can be done in the following mutually exclusive ways:
3
2 - 1
1 - 1 - 1

Therefore, when the two partitions are combined, you have the following mutually exclusive partitions that need to be diagnosed:
4 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 : Case 1
3 - 2 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 : Case 2
2 - 2 - 2 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 : Case 3


$\underline{\text{Computation For Case 1}}$
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{4}~$ ways of determining which $~4~$ pencils will be combined.  Once this is done, you can think of the $~4~$ pencils as forming one fused unit.
Therefore, you have $~7~$ units to permute among the boxes.
Therefore, the computation for Case 1 is
$$\binom{10}{4} \times 7!. \tag1 $$

$\underline{\text{Computation For Case 2}}$
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{3} \times \binom{7}{2}~$ ways of grouping $~3~$ pencils, and then grouping $~2~$ pencils.  Then, as in the previous section, you will have $~7~$ units to permute.
Therefore, the computation for Case 2 is
$$\binom{10}{3} \times \binom{7}{2} \times 7!. \tag2 $$

$\underline{\text{Computation For Case 3}}$
By analysis similar to that in the previous sections, the computation for Case 3 is
$$\binom{10}{2} \times \binom{8}{2} \times \binom{6}{2} \times 7! \times \frac{1}{3!}. \tag3 $$
The last factor in (3) above is an overcounting adjustment factor that accommodates that there are $~3!~$ different ways that the selection of the same $~3~$ pairs of pencils can be ordered.

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$
Simply add together the expressions for (1), (2), and (3), above.

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
The overcounting adjustment factor may be confusing to some readers.  One way of expanding your intuition here is to consider how many ways that there are to form $~2~$ pairs of elements from the set $~\{1,2,3,4\}.~$
The computation of $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{2} = 6~$ can be seen to be wrong, by considering that there are only three ways of forming the pairs, because there are only three other elements that can be paired with the element $~1.~$
So, the correct computation here is
$$\displaystyle \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{2} \times \frac{1}{2!}.$$

If the constraint that each student must receive at least one pencil was not there, we could distribute the pencils in $7^{10}$ ways, but this would leave student(s) with no pencil.
So we apply inclusion- exclusion  to get the answer of
$7^{10} -\binom71 6^{10} +\binom72 5^{10} -\binom73 4^{10} + \binom74 3^{10} - \binom75 2^{10} +\binom76 1^{10} = 29635200$
And if you have learnt about Stirling numbers of the second kind, you could compute ${10\brace 7}*7!$ to get the same answer

+1) That is the answer I was waiting for!

@drhab, Good to hear from you ! $;;$ :)
